# Undefined Keycloak Properties Authenticated and UserInfo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

I am trying to get the username and uid of the logged-in user.

In my application I used the `ReactKeycloakProvider` and `useKeycloak()`

```
import {ReactKeycloakProvider} from '@react-keycloak/web';
import keycloak from './keycloak';

const onKeycloakEvent = (event: any, error: any) => {
    console.log('onKeycloakEvent', event, error)
}

const onKeycloakTokens = (tokens: any) => {
    console.log('onKeycloakTokens', tokens)
}

const initOptions = {
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    checkLoginIframe: false
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ReactKeycloakProvider
            authClient={keycloak}
            initOptions={initOptions}
            onEvent={onKeycloakEvent}
            onTokens={onKeycloakTokens}
        >
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App/>
            </Provider>
        </ReactKeycloakProvider>

    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As a test I wanted to see if I can fetch the userInfo into my `Header.tsx`

```
import { useKeycloak} from "@react-keycloak/web";

const Header = () => {

    const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();

    console.log(keycloak);
    console.log(keycloak.authenticated);
    console.log(keycloak.userInfo);
    ...
```

**Problem**: For some reason the following logs output **undefined**

```
console.log(keycloak.authenticated);
console.log(keycloak.userInfo);
```

The example in the official documentation looks like this:

https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/blob/master/examples/react-router/src/pages/Home.tsx

and is almost identical to mine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I had to change the settings within Keycloak. So what I did was: Chose my Realm, and then under Clients -> Acess Type and change it from *confidential* to *public*.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in KeyCloak with public and confidential Clients is the Client-Secret. With 'public' you dont need the secret to initiate the login protocol which means in theory everybody can register/login to your KeyCloak. With the confidential type KeyCloak generates a unique Client-Secret for your Client that  you have to pass on in the options to start the logon process. With that you can make sure that only your Application (where you pass on the secret) gets to authenticate with your KeyCloak-Client.